# Eclipse 4 RCP: How can be the background color of a column changed in a TreeViewer?

Tags: treeview, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I have a TreeViewer with 3 TreeViewerColumns in it. It is possible to change the background color only for the first column?

My code is as follows:

```java
private void createTreeViewer(Composite parent) {
    TreeViewer treeViewer = new TreeViewer(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    treeViewer.getTree().setLinesVisible(true);
    treeViewer.getTree().setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

    TreeViewerColumn column = null;

    column = new TreeViewerColumn(treeViewer, SWT.LEFT);
    column.getColumn().setWidth(15);

    column = new TreeViewerColumn(treeViewer, SWT.LEFT);
    column.getColumn().setWidth(150);

    column = new TreeViewerColumn(treeViewer, SWT.LEFT);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a separate `ColumnLabelProvider` for each column (set with `TreeViewerColumn.setLabelProvider`.

`ColumnLabelProvider` has a `getBackground(element)` method which can be used to set the column color (or even individual cell colors).